# Dragging and dropping an image on picture box not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a picture box for displaying an image selected by a user using an open file dialog. But now I would like the user to drag and drop an image from the file system or other applications onto the picture box, so I subscribed to all drag and drop events for the picture box and assigned the correct drop over effects when the picture box drag over event occurs. However when an image file is placed on top of the picture box then the drag icon is replaced with a forbidden icon and the image assignment does not occur. I have instructed my form to accept drag and drop with this code in the form's constructor

```
AllowDrop = true;
```

And subscribed to the picture box drag over, drag enter and drag drop events with this code

```
 //other ctor code 
 pictureBox1 DragEnter += 
 PictureBox1_DragEnter;
 pictureBox1.DragDrop += 
 PictureBox1_DragDrop;
 pictureBox1.DragOver += 
 PictureBox1_DragOver;
}

 //on drag over assign the correct behavior
 private void  PictureBox1_DragOver(object? sender, DragEventArgs e){
   pictureBox1.DoDragDrop(e.Data, e.Effect);
}
 //on drop assign the image 
 private void PictureBox1_DragDrop(object? sender,DragEventArgs e){
   //assign the image to the picture box
 
 if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop){
   var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
   if(files.Length > 0){
    //get the image path
    var imagePath = files[0];
    //make sure its an image file
    var ext = Path.GetExtension(imagePath).ToLower();
    if(ext.Contains("png") || ext.Contains("jpg")){
       //assign the image
      pictureBox1.ImageLocation = imagePath:
    }else{
       Debug.WriteLine("The dropped file is not an image file");
    }
  }
 }
}
//on drag enter copy
private void PictureBox1_DragEnter(object? sender,DragEventArgs e){
  
 if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)){
   e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
 }
}
```

How do I make this work and get rid of the forbidden icon showing when I try to drag and drop an image over the picture box?

Comment: The Form allows a drop, but does the PictureBox? Did you set its `AllowDrop` property to `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two problems:

1. You should set `pictureBox1.AllowDrop = true`, it's a hidden property, intellisense won't show it, but it's effective.
2. `DoDragDrop` is used to begin a drag-and-drop operation, your usage is incorrect, so just remove it together with the `DragOver` handler.

Comment: Worked I thought allowing the AllowDrop to the form will make all children accept a drag and drop. Each control has its own allow drop property