# How to enable drag and drop image files into pictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I added both events:

```
this.DragEnter += CircularPicturebox_DragEnter;
this.DragDrop += CircularPicturebox_DragDrop;
```

I dragged the ciruclarpicturebox from the form1 designer toolbox.

but in form1 in runtime when I tried to drag some image to the pictureBox I'm getting this no entry traffic sign.

do I need to use mouse events to simulate drag and drop instead using just the dragenter and dragdrop events ?

[image: no entry]

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ColorAnalyzer
{
    class CircularPicturebox : PictureBox
    {
        private int borderSize = 2;
        private Color borderColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
        private Color borderColor2 = Color.HotPink;
        private DashStyle borderLineStyle = DashStyle.Solid;
        private DashCap borderCapStyle = DashCap.Flat;
        private float gradientAngle = 50F;

        public CircularPicturebox()
        {
            this.DragEnter += CircularPicturebox_DragEnter;
            this.DragDrop += CircularPicturebox_DragDrop;

            this.Size = new Size(300, 300);
            this.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        }

        private void CircularPicturebox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            // Check if files were dropped
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

                // Process the first dropped file (you can handle multiple files if needed)
                if (files.Length > 0)
                {
                    string imagePath = files[0];
                    if (File.Exists(imagePath))
                    {
                        // Load and analyze the image to extract its colors
                        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(imagePath);
                        List<Color> uniqueColors = ExtractUniqueColors(image);

                        // Display the extracted colors
                        DisplayColors(uniqueColors);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private List<Color> ExtractUniqueColors(Bitmap image)
        {
            List<Color> uniqueColors = new List<Color>();

            // Lock the bitmap's bits to access pixel data
            BitmapData bmpData = image.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, image.PixelFormat);

            // Calculate the number of bytes per pixel
            int bytesPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(image.PixelFormat) / 8;

            // Create a dictionary to keep track of unique colors
            Dictionary<Color, bool> uniqueColorDict = new Dictionary<Color, bool>();

            unsafe
            {
                byte* ptr = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;

                // Iterate through the image pixels
                for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
                    {
                        // Calculate the pixel's position in the byte array
                        int position = (y * bmpData.Stride) + (x * bytesPerPixel);

                        // Read the color of the current pixel
                        Color pixelColor = Color.FromArgb(
                            ptr[position + 2],   // Red
                            ptr[position + 1],   // Green
                            ptr[position]);      // Blue

                        // Check if the color is unique
                        if (!uniqueColorDict.ContainsKey(pixelColor))
                        {
                            uniqueColors.Add(pixelColor);
                            uniqueColorDict.Add(pixelColor, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Unlock the bitmap's bits
            image.UnlockBits(bmpData);

            return uniqueColors;
        }

        // Method to display the extracted colors
        private void DisplayColors(List<Color> colors)
        {
            // You can customize how you want to display the colors in your circular control here
            // For example, you can iterate through the colors and fill the circular control with each color
            // You can also limit the number of colors to be displayed if needed
            // This will depend on your specific requirements and how you want to visually represent the colors.
            // Clear the circular control
            this.Controls.Clear();

            int circleSize = 30; // Adjust the size of the circles
            int spacing = 10;   // Adjust the spacing between circles

            int centerX = this.Width / 2;
            int centerY = this.Height / 2;

            int currentX = centerX - (colors.Count * (circleSize + spacing)) / 2;

            foreach (Color color in colors)
            {
                // Create a new circular shape
                GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
                path.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(currentX, centerY - circleSize / 2, circleSize, circleSize));

                // Create a colored brush for the circle
                using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color))
                {
                    // Fill the circular shape with the color
                    this.CreateGraphics().FillPath(brush, path);
                }

                // Update the current X position for the next circle
                currentX += circleSize + spacing;
            }
        }

        private void CircularPicturebox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }

        //Properties
        [Category("RJ Code Advance")]
        public int BorderSize
        {
            get { return borderSize; }
            set
            {
                borderSize = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Category("RJ Code Advance")]
        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get { return borderColor; }
            set
            {
                borderColor = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Category("RJ Code Advance")]
        public Color BorderColor2
        {
            get { return borderColor2; }
            set
            {
                borderColor2 = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Category("RJ Code Advance")]
        public DashStyle BorderLineStyle
        {
            get { return borderLineStyle; }
            set
            {
                borderLineStyle = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Category("RJ Code Advance")]
        public DashCap BorderCapStyle
        {
            get { return borderCapStyle; }
            set
            {
                borderCapStyle = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        [Category("RJ Code Advance")]
        public float GradientAngle
        {
            get { return gradientAngle; }
            set
            {
                gradientAngle = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        //Overridden methods
        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
            //Fields
            var graph = pe.Graphics;
            var rectContourSmooth = Rectangle.Inflate(this.ClientRectangle, -1, -1);
            var rectBorder = Rectangle.Inflate(rectContourSmooth, -borderSize, -borderSize);
            var smoothSize = borderSize > 0 ? borderSize * 3 : 1;
            using (var borderGColor = new LinearGradientBrush(rectBorder, borderColor, borderColor2, gradientAngle))
            using (var pathRegion = new GraphicsPath())
            using (var penSmooth = new Pen(this.Parent.BackColor, smoothSize))
            using (var penBorder = new Pen(borderGColor, borderSize))
            {
                graph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                penBorder.DashStyle = borderLineStyle;
                penBorder.DashCap = borderCapStyle;
                pathRegion.AddEllipse(rectContourSmooth);
                //Set rounded region 
                this.Region = new Region(pathRegion);

                //Drawing
                graph.DrawEllipse(penSmooth, rectContourSmooth);//Draw contour smoothing
                if (borderSize > 0) //Draw border
                    graph.DrawEllipse(penBorder, rectBorder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dragging and dropping an image on picture box not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76959562/dragging-and-dropping-an-image-on-picture-box-not-working)

Comment: @IV. not it didn't answer.  the AllowDrop is not exist pictureBox1.AllowDrop = true there is no property for AllowDrop.  and in the link in the answer, he writes that's the AloowDrop property is hidden.  so far nothing worked.  i tried to google so far no solution/s.

Comment: Ok  i found the problem but not a solution yet.  when I'm running the application from the file explorer from d:\myapplication.exe then drag drop will work fine.  when running the application through visual studio it's not working.  i don't have a clue why and how to fix it.

Comment: Since you've narrowed it down to that, perhaps consider rewording your question in terms of admin/not admin with respect to the drag drop problem, and remove code that doesn't directly come to bear on this issue for a much more minimal repro. That would differentiate the question and reduce the appearance of it being a duplicate _and_ might be more answerable.

Comment: If you modify your DragEnter code like this, does the proper cursor display? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850870/e-data-getdatapresent-not-working-in-winforms-drag-and-drop-handler

Comment: @Jon when I reproduced the OPs problem, the issue was dragging from a process that wasn't elevated (Windows Explorer) to one with elevated permissions (because it was started from Visual Studio which was started with elevated permissions...). In this case, the `DragEnter` doesn't even fire, so there's no opportunity to set `e.Effect`. I don't have a solution for that, but that's what the problem is.